Unable to create a django project showing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DEBUG' in django5.0
I am new to django while using django version 1.11.29 it worked successful when upgraded to latest version 5.0.4
i can't create project django-admin startproject web_app
it not working and showing error as below
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
    ...<4 lines>...
    )
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.core import checks
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/checks/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import django.core.checks.caches  # NOQA isort:skip
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/checks/caches.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS, caches
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    signals.request_finished.connect(close_caches)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 87, in connect
    if settings.configured and settings.DEBUG:
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 91, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(_wrapped, name)
          ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'

is problem with python ,my python version 3.13.0a5+
I was tried to get django versio by python3 -m django --version it has been shown no module named django found

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors, post them as text formatted as code. Regarding your question: do you have the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable set by any chance?

Soory for that , DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE no change made for environment variables @AbdulAzizBarkat

Hmm, what do you get when you run echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in a terminal?

showing only a blank line

That's weird settings.configured should definitely be False if you're running django-admin startproject and don't have DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set. Try uninstalling and reinstalling Django, maybe your installation is somehow corrupted.

no use it's still not working  @AbdulAzizBarkat

can you edit your problem and share settings

@SujaySBadge they are creating the project (Running startproject) here and don't have any settings yet.

As I can see django is not installed in virtual environment. And djagno recomends to use virtual environment.
I suggest delete django using pip uninstall. then install django in virtual environment
